# c# how to list classes in dll, like java "jar tf path/to/my.jar"

Tags: java, c#, .net, .net-core

`jar tf path/to/my.jar` will list all Classes in Java, so with c# dll, how to list all classed in dll?
I am using .net core in linux, is it possible to list classes in dll in cli or in c# code?
for example, I want to list classes in Newtonsoft.Json.dll, how should I do this?

Comment: download some .net decompiler ?

Comment: You could try loading the assembly, like this `Assembly.LoadFile("path/to/Newtonsoft.Json.dll").GetTypes()`.

Answer (score 0):

In c# code you can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.90).aspx) or Jetbrains [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) but this is windows program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx) method to load assembly without executing it.

```
Assembly myassembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(NewtonSoftDllPath);

foreach (Type type in myassembly.GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}
```

Comment: It's **.NET Core**

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a ready-to-use in-built tool to do it, there are however many many utilities over there.

Do you want to have some fun? Write your own, proof of concept untested starter kit:

```
static Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(args[0]));

        foreach (var type in assembly.DefinedTypes)
            Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the proper NuGet packages (VS will suggest you the one to pick). Note that things are changed over the time (1.x -> 2.0) and you may need to adapt the example to the exact version you're targeting.